# Remove first character from JSON object using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm developing a Chrome Extension in which I send JSON with jQuery to a PHP file, which writes it into a JSON file.

My jQuery JSON object:

```
var detailsArray = { title : [{
                     "title" : title,
                     "url" : url, 
                     "username" : username, 
                     "password" : password
                   }]
};
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$dataToBeInserted = $_POST;
$file = "JSON.json";

//Open the file with read/write permission or show text
$fh = fopen($file, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
$stat = fstat($fh);

//Remove the last } character from the JSON file
ftruncate($fh, $stat['size']-1);

//Add the data from $dataToBeInserted to the file with a comma before it if there is data in file already.
if ($stat['size'] != 0) $append = ",";
echo fwrite($fh, $append . json_encode($dataToBeInserted,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES ) );
echo fwrite($fh, "}");

//Close the file
fclose($fh);
?>
```

My JSON file:

```
{
"Log In | Guild Wars 2" : [{
    "url" : "https://account.guildwars2.com/login", 
    "username" : "Guildwars2isawesome", 
    "password" : "randompassword",
    "title" : "Log In | Guild Wars 2"
}],
"library genesis" : [{
    "url" : "http://gen.lib.rus.ec/", 
    "username" : "awesomesauce", 
    "password" : "applesauce",
    "title" : "library genesis"
}],
"Google" : [{
    "url" : "http://www.google.com", 
    "username" : "someone@gmail.com", 
    "password" : "stackoverflowrules",
    "title" : "Google"
}]
}
```

After I add the JSON to the file, the JSON becomes this:

```
{
"Log In | Guild Wars 2" : [{
    "url" : "https://account.guildwars2.com/login", 
    "username" : "Guildwars2isawesome", 
    "password" : "randompassword",
    "title" : "Log In | Guild Wars 2"
}],
"library genesis" : [{
    "url" : "http://gen.lib.rus.ec/", 
    "username" : "awesomesauce", 
    "password" : "applesauce",
    "title" : "library genesis"
}],
"Google" : [{
    "url" : "http://www.google.com", 
    "username" : "someone@gmail.com", 
    "password" : "stackoverflowrules",
    "title" : "Google"
}]
,{
    "title": [
        {
            "title": "jQuery.getJSON() | jQuery API Documentation",
            "url": "http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/",
            "username": "",
            "password": ""
        }
    ]
}}
```

The problem is that the JSON I'm writing in jQuery has to have a `{` at the start of the object to not throw an error while I'm sending it. Is there any way to remove this first `{` of the object I'm writing to the file, without breaking the code?

Comment: Removing the last character of your file and adding a json string does not seem a very reliable way to generate a json file. I would just read the file, convert / decode it to an array, add whatever you need and encode and write the resulting array.

Comment: isnt it much easier to rebuild into an array again (since you are using php, `$contents[]= $dataToBeInserted`), then `json_encode()` again, and `file_put_contents` in the end

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the whole object again 
json_encode($dataToBeInserted..).
When converted to string, remove the 1st { and last } of $dataToBeInserted.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. I think I need to use 
`substr($dataToBeInserted, 1, -1);` But where do I put that?

I know nothing of PHP and I could use the help xD